# keras fit_generator can not spit data automatically?

Tags: validation, keras, split

I want to use keras fit_generator, I want to split test data, validation data automatically, but fit_generator can not set validation_split value.

Comment: You have to split data manually and use one generator for training and one for validation

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two generators, one for the training data and the second one for the validation data.
Than your fit function should look somehow like that:

```
model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator, validation_data=validation_generator, epochs=10)
```